# What is the reliable way to convert text data (document) to numerical data (vector) and save it for further use?

Tags: python, vector, nlp, gensim, doc2vec

As we know machines can't understand the text but it understands numbers so in NLP we convert text to some numeric representation and one of them is BOW representation. Here, my objective is to convert every document to some numeric representation and save it for future use. And I am following the below way to do that by converting text to BOW and saving it in a pickle file. My question is, whether we can do this in a better and reliable way? so that every document can be saved as some vector into a file and new documents are appended in the same way without losing any structure or information.

```
from gensim import corpora
import pickle

tokenized_corpus = [
    ['human', 'interface', 'computer'],
    ['survey', 'user', 'computer', 'system', 'response', 'time', 'survey'],
    ['eps', 'user', 'interface', 'system'],
    ['system', 'human', 'system', 'eps'],
    ['user', 'response', 'time'],
    ['trees'],
    ['graph', 'trees'],
    ['graph', 'minors', 'trees'],
    ['graph', 'minors', 'survey'],
    ['hello', 'system', 'i', 'love', 'graph', 'minor', 'trees']
]

file_name = 'corpus_sparse_rep.pkl'
bow = []
dct = corpora.Dictionary([tokenized_corpus[0]])  # added first doc as it needs corpus as argument
with open(file_name, 'wb+') as fp:
    # adding each doc sequentially
    for doc in tokenized_corpus:
        dct.add_documents([doc])  # updating vocab in dictionary
        bow.append(dct.doc2bow(doc))  # adding file representation to bow just to check contents before and after in
        # pickle
        pickle.dump(dct.doc2bow(doc), fp)
print(f'Saving bow data to pickle = {bow}')
print(f'Dictionary = {dct}')

# To load bow data from pickle file
pickle_data = []
with open(file_name, 'rb') as fr:
    while True:
        try:
            pickle_data.append(pickle.load(fr))
        except EOFError:
            break
print(f'Loading bow data from pickle = {pickle_data}')
# corpora.MmCorpus.serialize('t.mm', bow) # serialize data and save to market matrix (.mm) format

# Output
# Saving bow data to pickle = [[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)], [(0, 1), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1)], [(2, 1), (5, 1), (7, 1), (8, 1)], [(1, 1), (5, 2), (8, 1)], [(3, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1)], [(9, 1)], [(9, 1), (10, 1)], [(9, 1), (10, 1), (11, 1)], [(4, 1), (10, 1), (11, 1)], [(5, 1), (9, 1), (10, 1), (12, 1), (13, 1), (14, 1), (15, 1)]]
# Dictionary = Dictionary(16 unique tokens: ['computer', 'human', 'interface', 'response', 'survey']...)
# Loading bow data from pickle = [[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)], [(0, 1), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1)], [(2, 1), (5, 1), (7, 1), (8, 1)], [(1, 1), (5, 2), (8, 1)], [(3, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1)], [(9, 1)], [(9, 1), (10, 1)], [(9, 1), (10, 1), (11, 1)], [(4, 1), (10, 1), (11, 1)], [(5, 1), (9, 1), (10, 1), (12, 1), (13, 1), (14, 1), (15, 1)]]
```

Comment: I guess we would need to understand why you are saving your text representation in the first place. What is the objective? What is "future use"?

Comment: @chefhose, thanks for your question. The future use is that using this corpus I need to train the document similarity model to get the similarity score of unseen docs. But the twist here is, I need to add those unseen docs again into the corpus and re-build a similarity model. For that, I have to have the previous corpus saved somewhere.

Comment: But why specifically do you need the text representations? What sorts of operations will be performed against the representations? And what's the scale of documents involved - in count of documents and average document size in words? And how large and frequent are the arrival of new unseen docs? Have you looked for or worked through any online tutorials/examples which demonstrate similar capabilities to what you're seeking, and run into problems?

Comment: @gojomo, there are few reasons to save documents as vector representation. Major is that saving a document in raw format can cause GDPR issues due to the sensitive customer data. Next is document size considerably large and count can be in thousands, so converting it into representations seem safer in terms of computation, space and privacy.

Comment: Yes, but why do you/your-users need the representations in the 1st place? What sorts of operations will be performed against them? What is "considerably large"? (Is each document gigabytes or terabytes in size? There are no such examples in your `tokenized_corpus` above, and documents that large are unlikely to have useful compact vector representations - these techniques are far more commonly used on documents of dozens to thousands of words. And, even for documents with 100s-of-thousands of words – books – it is easy to store & index millions of such full texts on modest hardware.)

Comment: The generic reasons of "computation, space, & privacy" or "seems safer" are not, alone, strong reasons to vectorize text, without some specific sets of intended operations on those texts. (It's especially unlikely to resolve GDPR concerns, if there was personal info in the training data & there's still enough data in the operations performed on vectors for other business purposes. See for example https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.07886 or https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.05012.) And knowing the intended operations on the text determines what kind of compressed/condensed/vector-summarized options to choose.

Comment: @gojomo, first of all, saving raw docs into a vector representation is my point of view and not part of any requirement. This is because, while dealing with texts machine anyway will convert it into vectors after preprocessing. So my thought here is to save two operations from being executed again, 1- preprocessing 2- conversion from text to vectors. As per my specific use case, after building a document similarity model on a given corpus, I need to incorporate new documents again in my original corpus. So, in my view, it will be easier to convert the new doc to vector & update the corpus.

Comment: Coming back to the size of documents, I can expect up to 20 thousand docs each with a size of between 50 - 100 kb (with thousands of words), and when I convert docs to vector it is almost 5kb each. If you think I should consider a new approach to this problem and there is a better way to do it. I am happy to re-think.

Comment: OK, but after you integrate new docs into the corpus, what intended operations will you be performing ion the corpus? Why do you want vectors at all?

Comment: What are you referring to when you say intended operations? I need to build a new document similarity model after integrating the corpus. Does this answer your query for intended operations?

"Why do you want vectors at all?" - This is what I am trying to explain in all my comments. I tried to contact you on Twitter to make this clearer.